# using stroke width transform algorithm for text detection ( python3 - Windows )

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0

when i try to run this code to use stroke width tranform algorithm at [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyfzw292ns00xj1/swt_up.py?dl=0&fbclid=IwAR2VLcIu7oXNbteOCByJxhb1Tcl7vVg6S_n_lq_JGOJPP7XW5uHmshpojYo) , this error appear : 
D:/swt_up.py, line 305, in  _find_letters

fulllayer = np.zeros((shape_w, shape_h), dtype=np.uint16)

Memory error

```py
def _find_letters(swt, shapes, shape_h, shape_w):
    # STEP: Discard shapes that are probably not letters
    swts = []
    heights = []
    widths = []
    topleft_pts = []
    images = []

    for label,layer in shapes.items():
        #print(label)
        #print((layer[0],layer[1]))
        (nz_y, nz_x) = (layer[0],layer[1])
        east, west, south, north = max(nz_x), min(nz_x), max(nz_y), min(nz_y)
        width, height = east - west, south - north

        if width < 4 or height < 4:
            continue

        if width / height > 10 or height / width > 10:
            continue

        diameter = math.sqrt(width * width + height * height)
        median_swt = np.median(swt[(nz_y, nz_x)])
        #if diameter / median_swt > 10:
        #        continue

        #if width / shape_w > 0.4 or height / shape_h > 0.4:
        #         continue

        #if diagnostics:
        #     print (" written to image.")
        #     print(layer )
        #    cv2.imwrite('layer'+ str(label) +'.jpg', layer*255)

        # we use log_base_2 so we can do linear distance comparison later using k-d tree
        # ie, if log2(x) - log2(y) > 1, we know that x > 2*y
        # Assumption: we've eliminated anything with median_swt == 1
        swts.append([math.log(median_swt, 2)])
        heights.append([math.log(height, 2)])
        topleft_pts.append(np.asarray([north, west]))
        widths.append(width)

        fulllayer = np.zeros((shape_w, shape_h), dtype=np.uint16)
        for i in range(len(layer[0])):
            fulllayer[layer[0][i], layer[1][i]] = 1
        images.append(fulllayer)


    return swts, heights, widths, topleft_pts, images
```

How can I solve that problem? I can't find any bug, Maybe the error is from Window OS but i don't know how to fix.

Thanks all

Comment: What values of shape_w/shape_h are you passing ?

Comment: shape_w/shape_h are swt shape. You can see in my [Code link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyfzw292ns00xj1/swt_up.py?dl=0&fbclid=IwAR2VLcIu7oXNbteOCByJxhb1Tcl7vVg6S_n_lq_JGOJPP7XW5uHmshpojYo) @Yves Daoust

Comment: That doesn't tell me the values.

Comment: shape_w = 3300
shape_h = 2550

Comment: These are 16 MB images, which is reasonable.

Comment: There is another Python3 implementation of Stroke Width Transform here : https://github.com/ag-ds-bubble/swtloc

Answer (score 0):

> Memory error
>
> How can I solve that problem?

Operate on lower resolution greyscale images,
or on small horizontal bands of images,
if increasing the available memory is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

how much RAM has your pc?? In my past I tried the same code and after a bit of madness I realized that my windows 10 computer with 4GB of RAM cannot reach the end.

I figured the following problem, when the code "filters" strokes in letter it starts to create for each true letter an image with the same size of the original image, in which all the pixels of that layer are set to one and the other to zero. So at the end if there are 100 letter in the image you create 100 copy oof the image one for each letter. This is space for a pc.

I solved this problem changing a bit the code. For the layer I store a list of the coordinates that belong to that layer, and when I have too use it I create the 'map' and before go to the next I destroy it.
This is the code that I realized starting from the same code that you showed [GitHub/GoldMyr1994/IDTEXT](https://github.com/GoldMyr1994/IDTEXT)

Now I'm starting to thing that before look my code you can try another thing.
I see this line

```
 fulllayer = np.zeros((shape_w, shape_h), dtype=np.uint16)
```

But I think that you only need a boolean map so you can try to set the type to np.bool and hope that the memory that you save is enough to reach the end of the code.